# HP M2N68-LA Motherboard graphics

Tags: motherboard, hp-pavilion

I have a odd problem that I can not seem to fix, I have a motherboard M2N68-LA (Narra Series) from a HP Pavilion and can not seem to get any graphics working. I have Ubuntu Server 13.10 installed, the computer boots up and I can access via SSH but there is absolutely no display on the connected monitor. I don't even see any postings when the computer is booting. I am using the on-board graphics card and tried installing another graphics card and connecting another monitor with no avail. 
    I have tried removing the CMOS battery and setting the CMOS reset jumper but still no go. Does anyone have ANY ideas? Yes I can access via SSH but if something goes wrong with the SSH I am SOL ;-)